# Regex - I need to find something then copy what is after it

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this:

```
<A NAME=speech26><b>SIR HUGH EVANS</b></a>
<blockquote>
<A NAME=1.1.58>Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.59>despise one that is false, or as I despise one that</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.60>is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.61>beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.62>peat the door for Master Page.</A><br>
<p><i>Knocks</i></p>
<A NAME=1.1.63>What, hoa! Got pless your house here!</A><br>
</blockquote>
```

I want to find all the text and get it out into something like this

```
Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do
despise one that is false, or as I despise one that
is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I
beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will
peat the door for Master Page.
What, hoa! Got pless your house here!
```

I tried `<A NAME=[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+>`, but it doesn't work, and also doesn't achieve what I want to do. Can someone help?

Comment: You probably need to use `beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option, using `re.findall`:

```
text = "<A NAME=1.1.58>Shall I tell you a lie? " # ... your input from above
output = re.findall(r'<A NAME=\d+\.\d+\.\d+>(.*?)(?=</A>)', text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print(output)

['Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do',
 'despise one that is false, or as I despise one that',
 'is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I',
 'beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will',
 'peat the door for Master Page.',
 'What, hoa! Got pless your house here!']
```

But note that in general using regex to parse HTML/XML content is not a good thing.  If you are certain that your target content would only ever occur in between the type of `<A>` tags you showed above, then you might get away with using regex.

Comment: what does "(.*?)(?=</A>)" do?

Comment: It matches all content up to, but not including, the _first_ closing `</A>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
text = """<A NAME=speech26><b>SIR HUGH EVANS</b>
</a><blockquote>
<A NAME=1.1.58>Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.59>despise one that is false, or as I despise one that</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.60>is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.61>beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.62>peat the door for Master Page.</A><br>
<p><i>Knocks</i></p>
<A NAME=1.1.63>What, hoa! Got pless your house here!</A><br>
</blockquote>"""

output = re.findall(r'<A NAME=\d\.\d\.\d*>(.*?)(?=</A>)', text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print(output)
```

Output

```
['Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do', 'despise one that is false, or as I despise one that', 'is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I', 'beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will', 'peat the door for Master Page.', 'What, hoa! Got pless your house here!']
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML/XML/JSON using regex is really like writing a bad quality code. HTML may contain repeating nested structures which may lead to unexpected results while parsing with regex.

You can use `Beautiful Soup` library in python and parse your given HTML to extract desired output.

Here is a sample python code using `Beautiful Soup`

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<A NAME=speech26><b>SIR HUGH EVANS</b>
</a><blockquote>
<A NAME=1.1.58>Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.59>despise one that is false, or as I despise one that</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.60>is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.61>beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will</A><br>
<A NAME=1.1.62>peat the door for Master Page.</A><br>
<p><i>Knocks</i></p>
<A NAME=1.1.63>What, hoa! Got pless your house here!</A><br>
</blockquote>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for aTag in soup.find_all('a', {'name': re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+')}):
 print(aTag.get_text())
```

Which gives following output as you need,

```
Shall I tell you a lie? I do despise a liar as I do
despise one that is false, or as I despise one that
is not true. The knight, Sir John, is there; and, I
beseech you, be ruled by your well-willers. I will
peat the door for Master Page.
What, hoa! Got pless your house here!
```

Notice, I've used regex here as well, but in a limited space, just to tell I am interested in all 'a' tags where value of `name` attribute is of this `\d+\.\d+\.\d+` pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<A NAME=\d+\.\d+\.\d+>(.*)(?=</A>)
```

**Explanation**

- `<A NAME=\d+\.\d+\.\d+>` - Will match something like this`<A NAME=1.1.112>`
- `(.*)` - Match anything except newline zero or more time.
- `(?=</A>)` - Positive look ahead. Matches `</A>`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4iw9k/2)